# android Difference between handler.postAtTime and handler.postDelayed

Tags: android, handler

Please tell me the difference between handler.postAtTime and handler.postDelayed in android.And         also please guide me when to use handler.postAtTime and when to use handler.postDelayed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From documentation:

For `postAtTime`:

> `public final boolean postAtTime (Runnable r, long uptimeMillis)`
>   `...`
>   `uptimeMillis`     The **absolute time at which the callback should run**, using the uptimeMillis() time-base.
>   `...`

And for `postDelayed`:

> `public final boolean postDelayed (Runnable r, long delayMillis)`
>   `...`
>   `delayMillis`  The **delay** (in milliseconds) until the Runnable will be executed.
>   `...`

---

If this is still not clear, `postDelayed()` run something after X millisecond from current time. While `postAtTime()` runs something at specified time `XX:YY:ZZ.mmm`.